# Rating normalisation

Tags: python, for-loop, pandas

I have next pandas DataFrame df:

```
user item rating
1    1    1
1    2    1
1    3    3
2    1    2
2    2    2
2    3    1
...
```

I want normalise the rating, define all values of rating between 0 and 1. The method is very simple, just divide every value of some user through the maximum of this user.

I have created next code:

```
ratingNormalised = []

for user in df['user'].unique:
    dfUser = df[df['user'] == user]
    userNormalised = (dfUser['rating']/max(dfUser['rating'])).tolist()
    ratingNormalised.extend(userNormalised)

df['ratingNorm'] = Series(ratingNormalised, index=df.index)
```

Is it possible to find some better solution, which could be more pythonic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

groupby the user and apply a lambda:

```
In [73]:

df['norm rating'] = df.groupby('user')['rating'].apply(lambda x: x/x.max())
df

Out[73]:
   user  item  rating  norm rating
0     1     1       1     0.333333
1     1     2       1     0.333333
2     1     3       3     1.000000
3     2     1       2     1.000000
4     2     2       2     1.000000
5     2     3       1     0.500000
```